# Cubic root epsilon delta proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, radicals, epsilon-delta

I'm reviewing this epsilon delta proof for the continuity of the cubic root:

[image]

but I can't see why is so evident that $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{xc}+\sqrt[3]{c^2}\ge \sqrt[3]{c^2}$. Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $c\neq0$. So, if $x$ is close enough to $c$, $x$ and $c$ will have the same sign and therefore $xc>0$. Therefore $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{cx}>0$, and this implies that $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{cx}+\sqrt[3]{c^2}>\sqrt[3]{c^2}$.

Comment: Thank you José Carlos.

Comment: So it might be more precise to say we choose $\delta = \min(\epsilon \sqrt[3]{c^2}, |c|/2)$.

Comment: @aschepler did you say that because we need to estimate the product $cx$ so if we request $\delta < |c|/2$ then from $|x-c|<\delta<|c|/2$ we deduce that $c-|c|/2 < x < c+|c|/2$, so $x$ is positive if $c$ is positive and $x$ is negative if $c$ is negative because in both cases is $c/2 < x < 3c/2$; but for both to be satisfied (continuity and sign accordance) we have to impose $\delta = \min(\varepsilon \sqrt[3]{c^2},|c|/2)$? Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Exactly.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Oh, except in the negative case it would be $3c/2 < x < c/2$ instead.

Comment: @aschepler yes, you're right! Thanks again for your kindness in answering me.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers above. I am reviewing this myself, and I was just wondering if it is reasonable to argue that $(x^\frac{1}{3})^2+c^\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{1}{3}+c^\frac{2}{3}$ is a quadratic equation in $x^\frac{1}{3}$ leading to the argument that $(x^\frac{1}{3})^2+c^\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{1}{3}+c^\frac{2}{3} \geq \frac{3c^\frac{2}{3}}{4}$ by evaluating the quadratic at its vertex $x=-\frac{c}{8}$. We know that the quadratic is convex since the coefficient of the squared term is positive, so the vertex is the absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for the denominator, $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{c^2}=x^{2/3}+c^{2/3}\geq 0$, so $|g(x)-g(c)|\geq\frac{|x-c|}{|cx|^{1/3}}$.

We can now bound $|x|$ by (if $|x-a|<\delta$, which we can do by choosing $\delta$ as the minimum of 2 numbers) $|x|<2|a|$ (prove this as a good exercise for working with limits) , so it follows that we can bound

$$|g(x)-g(c)|\leq\frac{|x-c|}{|c|^{2/3}}$$ and we can use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition easily to prove $g$ is continuous