# Prove that $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous at $c \ne 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

My question is regarding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797768/cubic-root-epsilon-delta-proof) old question.

The old question was about proving that $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous at $c \ne 0$. Basicailly, the question was why it is that $$\sqrt[3]{xc} \ge 0.$$ and from the response/comments, I gathered thatthis is so becasue either $x, c <0$ or $x, c >0$ as long as we take $\delta=\min\left(\epsilon\sqrt[3]{c}, \dfrac{|c|}{2}\right)$. I am trying to verify this. If $\epsilon\sqrt[3]{c}< \dfrac{|c|}{2}$, I obtained the desired result by a simple manipulation of the inequalities. However, if $\epsilon\sqrt[3]{c}> \dfrac{|c|}{2}$, how do we verify that either $x, c <0$ or $x, c >0$? Is the choice of $\delta$ incorrect? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that, if $|x-c|<\frac{c}{2}$, then $x$ and $c$ have the same sign (i.e. $xc>0$). This can be done as follows:

Suppose first $c>0$. If $|x-c|<\frac{c}{2}$, then
$$
-\frac{c}{2}<x-c<\frac{c}{2}
$$
In particular,
$$
x>c-\frac{c}{2}=\frac{c}{2}>0
$$
Thus, $x>0$.

Suppose now that $c<0$. If $|x-c|<\frac{-c}{2}$, then
$$
\frac{c}{2}<x-c<\frac{-c}{2}
$$
In particular,
$$
x<c+\frac{-c}{2}=\frac{c}{2}<0
$$
Thus, $x<0$.